# Android:How to change the background color of the options menu when selected?

Tags: android

I have created an an options menu in my application. I want to change the background color of the menu item selected. Please help me doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You must try this code which will change your menu color with the menu text.

```
 private void setMenuBackground() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                try {

                        LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);

                        new Handler().post( new Runnable() {
                            public void run () {
                                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    }
                    catch (InflateException e) {
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
}
```